# Is there a way to redirect mail from a specific address to come to an address of my choosing using Exchange 2010?

Tags: email, exchange-2010

Can email from person@external.com sent to user1@mycompany.com & user2@mycompany.com be re-directed to me@mycompany.com using Exchange?  If not using Exchange alone, is there any way at all to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed it by creating a new transport rule in Organisation configuration > Hub Transport.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. A mailbox can have more than one email address pointing to it. Simply add those email addresses as additional ones to your mailbox.

Answer (score 0):

In the Delivery Options on the Mail Flow Settings tab of the properties of the mailbox you can set the option to forward to another recipient (user or group).

Comment: The mail i needed to re-direct was coming from an external source so i didn't have access to these mailbox settings.